# Method to fill forms across many sites - jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

After working in good ole' c++ all day, I like to have a few javascript/jQuery side projects that are purely for fun. One of most intriguing things about jQuery is the ease of filling forms. All you need is a selector and the `.val()` method and you are golden. However, what would be the most efficient way to fill forms across multiple sites? The form elements would have different selectors obviously. So is there a way to have a script inspect a page and determine the selectors needed, then hand those selectors to jQuery for filling?

Just an intriguing thought, probably not possible, but I thought I'd ask anyway, if only to satisfy my curiosity. So is something like I described above possible? Dynamically getting the selectors off of a page?

**Thanks!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're doing something like making an extension and not trying to do some cross-domain scripting (which won't work btw), the HTML should still be the same across sites.

You can select `$('textarea')`, `$('select')`, `$('textfield')`, `$('input')` etc, without worrying about things like classes and IDs.

Comment: FF extension, if I were to do anything.